# Issue using GIT with GRUNT automated task

Tags: git, gruntjs

I'm using [Roots](http://roots.io) development theme, which uses grunt for css/js minification/concatenation/hinting.

I'm just getting started using `git`. The problem I'm facing is that when I checkout a branch, commit, and then checkout the master, the automated grunt task sees the changes made and compiles a new version. At this point I can't switch branches because I have uncommited changes (the auto compiled css file).

Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an ideal world you shouldn't be committing your compiled css. The changes you make are in the less/sass/stylus files which you then commit with your updates/changes.

When you install the project, update files or switch branches the css should be recompiled to reflect the branch you are on or changes you have made. You can then merge your branch into master, `git pull`, and the watch will re-compile your css showing you the updated version.

To stop your css from being seen by git add the directory to your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks!